# Missing module error while running unit test

Tags: 8, testing

I am trying to run a unit test for one of my contributed modules in my local development environment. But it keeps throwing an error:

```
$:/path/to/web$ sudo -u www-data -E phpunit -c core/phpunit.xml profiles/abc/modules/contrib/entity_clone/tests/src/Functional/EntityCloneContentTest.php
PHPUnit 6.5.9 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Testing Drupal\Tests\entity_clone\Functional\EntityCloneContentTest
F                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 8.49 seconds, Memory: 4.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Drupal\Tests\entity_clone\Functional\EntityCloneContentTest::testContentEntityClone
Unable to install modules entity_clone, block, node, datetime due to missing modules entity_clone.

/path/to/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Test/FunctionalTestSetupTrait.php:481
/path/to/web/core/tests/Drupal/Tests/BrowserTestBase.php:578
/path/to/web/core/tests/Drupal/Tests/BrowserTestBase.php:406
/path/to/web/core/modules/node/tests/src/Functional/NodeTestBase.php:33
/path/to/web/profiles/abc/modules/contrib/entity_clone/tests/src/Functional/EntityCloneContentTest.php:50

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

Any idea what is wrong here? I have tried with a few other modules also, same error.
Do I have to do anything additional to add my profiles in the phpunit.xml?

BR/Pratip

Answer (score 1):

We ran into the same issue with the 'cookies_etracker' submodule of 'etracker'.

I guess this happens, if you have a submodule AND a composer.json in your main module (not auto-generated by Drupal). Then I guess the dependencies for the tests are not auto-generated, while Drupal.org does it if no composer.json is present in the repo.

Someone had a similar problem described here:
https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2018-06-21/sub-module-dependencies and here https://github.com/acquia/coding-standards-php/issues/6

I think it's a bug / conflict in the Drupal.org Testbot:
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalci_testbot/issues/3250126

Currently the only way to solve this is to remove the composer.json from the parent module entirely (which might not be wanted in most cases).

Comment: Appreciate your help. Will test it in a few days.

Comment: @PratipGhosh have you been successful? Would be nice for others here to know, if it helped or how you fixed it.